# Traveling from United States to England twice within one year

Tags: visas, us-citizens, england

I am a United States citizen and studied abroad in England from September 1, 2016 to December 16, 2016 without a visa. I am now planning to return to London on March 24, 2017 and leave on April 5 2017.

Do I need to get any specific visa or is the fact that it is just a vacation allow me to not need a visa?

Comment: Does "temporary student visa" mean that you got a stamp in your passport at the immigration desk which said something like "leave to enter for six months"?  If so, that was not a student visa; it was an entry stamp.  A visa is a sticker that is placed in your passport before you travel to the UK, usually by the consulate in your country of residence.

Answer (score 2):

You were in the UK last year as a short-term student, I assume you were admitted under Paragraph A57A of the rules, "[Persons seeking to enter the UK for short-term study](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-3-students)". You now want to enter the UK as a visitor.

> Do I need to get any specific visa or is the fact that it is just a
>   vacation allow me to not need a visa?

U. S. Citizens to not require an entry clearance prior to arrival in the UK. They just 'show up' and have a landing interview. This is explained in [Paragraph 23A of the Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk)...

> A person who is not a visa national and who is seeking leave to enter
>   on arrival in the United Kingdom for a period not exceeding 6 months
>   for a purpose for which prior entry clearance is not required under
>   these Rules may be granted such leave, for a period not exceeding 6
>   months.

So it's OK.

We always advise visitors who are returning shortly after a previous visit to be careful to carry supporting documentation because there's always the possibility of running afoul of [Paragraph 320 (1)](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal)...

> the fact that entry is being sought for a purpose not covered by these
>   Rules;

There are some removal cases in the archives here bearing this out. If your landing interview is successful, you will be admitted under [Appendix V of the Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules).

That constitutes your answer along with all the relevant links.

Answer (score 0):

Until Mrs May pulls something like Trump has done, you don't need a visa. You would even be allowed some studying (up to 30 days) provided incidental to (not the main reason for your) trip.

Comment: Non sequitur and inappropriate.